# Why is $e^{-ix}$ an odd function?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, exponential-function, complex-integration, even-and-odd-functions

My physics prof pulled this out of the air to swap the limits on an integral:

$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ix} \, dx = \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{ix} \, dx$

"because the integrand is odd."

So far as I can tell:

$f(x) = e^{-ix}$

$$= \cos(-x) + i \sin(-x)$$

$$= \cos(x) - i \sin(x)$$

$f(-x) = e^{ix}$

$$= \cos(x) + i \sin(x)$$

$-f(x) = -e^{-ix} $

$$= - \cos(x) + i \sin(x), $$

therefore

$-f(x) \neq f(-x) $

and the function is not odd?

I'm guessing 9:1 I'm wrong, someone let me know why :')

Comment: First of all, those integrals you wrote don't exist. And second, $\exp(ix)$ is not odd, as you checked. I don't know what type of calculations are you doing with divergent integrals.

Comment: Just doing some real integrals using complex analysis, was splitting a cosine

Comment: @Anonymizer Ok. If your question was solved then it's okay for me. But remember, just as a side note, you can split trigonometric functions using $e^{\pm ix}$ but you cannot split their respective integrals if you don't check convergence. That's all.

Comment: @Riemann Thanks! I guess he was just changing from x to - x,

Comment: @Edd Yeah we were doing something of the sort: $\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos(x) \ dx = \frac{1}{2} \left( \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{ix} \ dx + \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{-ix} \ dx \right)=
\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ix} \ dx $, to get things into form for integration on the complex plane, discarding the imaginary part by Jordans Lemma, etc

Comment: @Edd Those "integrals" are not integrals in the context of this post.  They are distributions and are in fact Fourier transforms of the Heaviside function.

Comment: @MarkViola that is exactly correct :)

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring any issues of the integral existing,

$$
\int_0^\infty f(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^0 f(-x) dx
$$

is true for every function $f$, not just odd functions. This is simply a variable substitution. Setting $u = -x$, we have

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty f(x) dx &= \int_0^{-\infty}f(-u) (-1) du\\
&=-\int_{-\infty}^0 f(-u) (-1) du\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^0 f(-u) du\\
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Physicists often use a “free” language in the math domain.;-)

You are, of course, right — the integrand is not an odd function.

I guess that the author wanted to express something as this, having in mind that the **identity** ($x \mapsto x$) **is an odd fuction**:

- LHS integrand is $\ e^{-ix}$ and integration is for values in interval  $ [0, \infty)$.
- Every $x$ we may express as $-(-x)\ $, or as $-y$, where $y = -x$. Then
  $$ e^{-ix} = e^{(-i)(-y)} = e^{iy}$$
- But if $x \in [0, \infty)$, then $y \in (-\infty, 0]$, so by the substitution $y = -x$ we obtain

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ix} \, \mathrm dx = \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{iy} \, \mathrm dy = \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{ix} \, \mathrm dx$$

Comment: I do however wish that my lecturer would choose to use more precise language when teaching complex analysis and Green's functions, as this is not the first time I've been left scratching my head trying to figure out what he means.  It's even in the lecture notes - "This integrand is odd, therefore:" I was convinced I didn't understand odd and even functions on the complex plane for HOURS :')